# Differential equation of the form $x^2y''+(1-2p)xy'+(p^2-q^2)y=x^n$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, substitution

$$x^2y''+(1-2p)xy'+(p^2-q^2)y=x^n
$$
can be written in the form 
$$
x^a(x^b(x^cy)')'=x^n,
$$
where
$$
a=1+2p\pm q,
b=1\mp2q, c=-p\pm q.
$$
As you can see there are two possible sets of values of $a,b,c$. Both sets of values gives **equivalent** differential equations, so they should lead to the same general solution.

However, if you try to solve it, you will start by integrating both sides of 
$$
(x^b(x^cy)')'=x^{n-a},
$$
and the antiderivative of RHS is clearly dependent on the value of $n-a$: when $n-a=-1$, RHS will be integrated to give $\ln x$; otherwise it will be $\frac{x^{n-a+1}}{n-a+1}$. Those two cases clearly do NOT lead to the same general solution. **Now, I can choose the values of $p,q$** so that $1+2p-q=n+1$ but $1+2p-q\neq n+1$, that is, one possible value of $a$ gives $\ln(x)$ while the other doesn't. So the two values of $a$ lead to different general solutions. However, changing the sign of $q$ does NOT change the differential equation, so how can it lead to a change in general solution? **What is wrong?**

EDIT: I focus on the value of $p,q$ that gives $\ln x$ only.

Comment: To compare your method to an alternative solution method: Your equation is Euler-Cauchy with basis solutions $x^{p+q}$ and $x^{p-q}$. If $n$ is neither of these exponents, then a solution $Ax^n$ exists, with $A[n(n-1)+(1-2p)n+p^2-q^2]=1$, so that $A=\frac1{(n-p)^2-q^2}=\frac1{(n-p-q)(n-p+q)}$, so that in the end there is symmetry regarding the sign of $q$.

Comment: @LutzL Yes, but what about the values of $p,q$ that give rise to $\ln x$?

Comment: Are you sure about the formula for $a$? It should be without the factor $2$, $a=1+p\pm q$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct the exponent $a=1+p\pm q$.

---

So continue to carry out the integration for the **general case** $(n-p)^2\ne q^2$.
$$
x^b(x^cy)'=\frac{x^{n-a+1}}{n-a+1}+C
\\
(x^cy)'=\frac{x^{n-a+1-b}}{n-a+1}+Cx^{-b}
\\
x^cy=\frac{x^{n-a-b+1}}{(n-a+1)(n-a-b+2)}+Cx^{-b+1}+D
\\
y=\frac{x^{n-a-b-c+1}}{(n-a+1)(n-a-b+2)}+Cx^{-b-c+1}+Dx^{-c}
$$
and as $a+b=2+p\mp q$ the factors in the denominator are $n-p\mp q$ and $n-p\pm q$, which is symmetric in the sign before $q$.

---

The **exceptional cases** are those where $n+1-a=0\iff n=p\pm q$ or where $n+1-a-b=0\iff n=p\mp q$.

The **first case** $n+1-a=0$ gives in the first integration
$$
x^b(x^cy)'=\ln x+C.
$$
The second integration proceeds via partial integration to 
$$
x^cy=Cx^{1-b}+\int x^{-b}\ln x\,dx=Cx^{1-b}+\frac{x^{1-b}\ln x}{1-b}-\int \frac{x^{-b}}{1-b}dx
$$
where the last integral can be combined with the first term.
$$
y=Cx^{p\pm q}+Dx^{p\mp q}\pm\frac{x^{p\pm q}\ln x}{2q}=Cx^{p+q}+Dx^{p-q}+\frac{x^n\ln x}{2(n-p)}.
$$
Constants $C,D$ were reassigned and relabeled deliberately from one step to the next.

In the **second case** $n+2-a-b=0$ the computation branches off from the regular solution at the second integration giving
$$
x^cy=\frac{\ln x}{(n-a+1)}+Cx^{-b+1}+D
\\
y=\frac{x^{p\mp q}\ln x}{n-p\mp q}+Cx^{p\pm q}+Dx^{p\mp q}
=\frac{x^n\ln x}{2(n-p)}+Cx^{p+ q}+Dx^{p- q}
$$
Constants $C,D$ were reassigned and relabeled deliberately from one step to the next.

So indeed both solution variants lead to the same general solution formula.

Comment: Read my question carefully: I focus on the case that gives rise to $\ln x$. You solution is only valid for $n-a\neq 1$

Comment: Oh ok, I have evaluated $a,b$ wrong... Thanks a lot!